# Python while loop is not functioning correctly (beginner)

Tags: python-3.x

I'm still quite new to Python and am confused as to what's happening with a program I'm working on.  The code is below.  The problem is the code is never running any of the if/elif/else lines.  It just keeps cycling the menu and inputs.  I'm using 3.2.

```
# Program to Add, Subtract, Multiply, and Divide

def printmenu():
    print("Calculator v0.01")
    print("[A]dd Two Numbers")
    print("[S]ubtract Two Numbers")
    print("[M]ultiply Two Numbers")
    print("[D]ivide Two Numbers")
    print("[Q]uit the Program")

choice = "x"

while choice.lower != "q":
    printmenu()
    choice = input("What would you like to do? ")
    firstnum = input("What is the first number? ")
    secnum = input("What is the second number? ")
    if choice.lower == "a":
        print("The answer is ",  (firstnum + secnum))
    elif choice.lower == "s":
        print("The answer is ",  (firstnum - secnum))
    elif choice.lower == "m":
        print("The answer is ",  (firstnum * secnum))
    elif choice.lower == "d":
        print("The answer is ",  (firstnum / secnum))
    else:
        print("Choice not recognized.  Try again!")
```

P.S. - This is my first post on here, so if I'm not doing something properly then please let me know.

Thanks!

JT

Comment: Your post is fine - your question title is indicative of the content of the post/what you want answered, you supply the code that is not working, you say what is not working and what you expect to happen instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
>>> "a".lower
<built-in method lower of str object at 0x0000000001EBBBC0>
>>> "a".lower()
'a'
>>> "a".lower == "a"
False
>>> "a".lower() == "a"
True
>>>
```

I think you meant lower(), not lower ;)

Comment: Yes, that was it!  Of course now it's not acting correctly because I didn't convert the nums to float/int so 5 +2 = 52, but that's easy enough to fix by putting float(input()).  Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

all inbuilt functions in python should be called using `()`. So use

```
if choice.lower()!="q":
```

Only then the function is called. Else the value is always returned `False`, since no function is executed

Answer (score 0):

1. Replace `lower` by `lower()`
2. Use `float(fisrtnum) + float(secnum)` as otherwise it will just concatenate the char and gives 23 for '2'+'3'